# Unmarshal json field into struct field of type *regexp.Regexp

Tags: json, regex, go

I'm trying to unmarshal a JSON file with some rules based on regex into my structure.

See below my structure.

```golang
// GithubProjectMatcher matches a repository with a project
type GithubProjectMatcher struct {
    Rules map[string]GithubProjectMatcherRule `json:"rules,omitempty"`
}

// GithubProjectMatcherRule rule that matches a repository to a project
type GithubProjectMatcherRule struct {
    URL *regexp.Regexp `json:"url,omitempty"`
}
```

See here my json

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Project One": { "url": "tabia|varys|garo" },
    "Project Two": { "url": "(?i)lem\\-" },
  }
}
```

If I hardcode these regexes in code they are working.

e.g.

```golang
regexp.MustCompile("tabia|varys|garo")
```

What has to be done to be able to Decode these into my struct?

I tried decoding as following.

```golang
f, err := os.Open("rules.json")
if err != nil {
   return err
}
defer f.Close()
err := json.NewDecoder(f).Decode(&m)
if err != nil {
   return err
}
```

Comment: You can't, not directly. You need a custom type that has the regex type as a field, then you have the custom type implement the json unmarshaler interface. You can have the field embedded if you want to be able to use the regex methods directly through the custom type.

Comment: Or you can write a custom `UnmarshalJSON` on `GithubProjectMatcherRule`. Either way, you want to store the RE in JSON as a plain string, and `Compile` it to a `regexp.Regexp` yourself during unmarshaling.

Comment: Thanks, I should have known, done that before. Will share the result as an answer here as well for future readers.

Comment: Which part of the documentation of package encoding/json hints at this being possible at all? Is *regexp.Regexp among the types this package can handle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is as following:

By implementing the TextMarshaler and TextUnmarshaler interfaces you can define how a value should be marshalled or unmarshalled.

https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/#TextMarshaler
https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/#TextUnmarshaler

```golang
// GithubMetadataFactory allows to provide a custom generated metadata
type GithubMetadataFactory func(repo github.Repository) Metadata

// GithubProjectMatcher matches a repository with a project
type GithubProjectMatcher struct {
    Rules map[string]GithubProjectMatcherRule `json:"rules,omitempty"`
}

// GithubProjectMatcherRule rule that matches a repository to a project
type GithubProjectMatcherRule struct {
    URL *Regexp `json:"url,omitempty"`
}


// Regexp adds unmarshalling from json for regexp.Regexp
type Regexp struct {
    *regexp.Regexp
}

// UnmarshalText unmarshals json into a regexp.Regexp
func (r *Regexp) UnmarshalText(b []byte) error {
    regex, err := regexp.Compile(string(b))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    r.Regexp = regex

    return nil
}

// MarshalText marshals regexp.Regexp as string
func (r *Regexp) MarshalText() ([]byte, error) {
    if r.Regexp != nil {
        return []byte(r.Regexp.String()), nil
    }

    return nil, nil
}
```

See here for a fully working example in the Go Playground. https://play.golang.org/p/IS60HuuamLM

For more complex datatypes you can also implement the json Marshaler and Unmarshaler interface on your type.

https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshaler
https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler

Examples of both can be found here as well.

https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/

Answer (score 2):

(Un)marshaling a regular expression is pretty easy. It just requires creating a custom type that embeds `regexp.Regexp`:

```
import "regexp"

// MyRegexp embeds a regexp.Regexp, and adds Text/JSON
// (un)marshaling.
type MyRegexp struct {
    regexp.Regexp
}

// Compile wraps the result of the standard library's
// regexp.Compile, for easy (un)marshaling.
func Compile(expr string) (*MyRegexp, error) {
    re, err := regexp.Compile(expr)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return &MyRegexp{*re}, nil
}

// UnmarshalText satisfies the encoding.TextMarshaler interface,
// also used by json.Unmarshal.
func (r *MyRegexp) UnmarshalText(text []byte) error {
    rr, err := Compile(string(text))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    *r = *rr
    return nil
}

// MarshalText satisfies the encoding.TextMarshaler interface,
// also used by json.Marshal.
func (r *MyRegexp) MarshalText() ([]byte, error) {
    return []byte(r.String()), nil
}
```

Comment: I now realize you posted the solution in the same time as I did. Nice we where both very close with our solution